# Angular-snap doesn't work together with ngSticky

Tags: css, angularjs, sticky, snap.js

trying to use together [Angular-Snap](https://github.com/jtrussell/angular-snap.js) with [ngSticky](https://github.com/d-oliveros/ngSticky) but it doesn't work, panel which should stay *sticky* is being scrolled.

I've prepared two examples:

- Example with Angular-Snap which **doesn't work**: https://plnkr.co/edit/ARhUti3jJCEjB8sLL5q0?p=preview
- Example without Angular-Snap which **works**: 
  https://plnkr.co/edit/QJSQelcdUP2AamFBuNiH?p=preview

You can expand in both examples accordion panel and try to scroll to see the difference. Actually I've tried multiple solutions to make the element be **sticky** but no one have worked with Angular-Snap

If I remove in **1st**, *non-working example* `angular-snap.css` file it begins to work, but obviously I need it. I couldn't debug this issue further, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found a workaround :) I'm smiling because it isn't first time when I find a solution by myself shortly after I'm posting a question.

I've created the following directive:

```
.directive("stickyElement", function ($window) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
            console.log("scrolled");
        });

        $(".snap-content").bind("scroll", function(event){
            var scrolledUp = $(".snap-content").scrollTop();
            console.log("from top: " + scrolledUp);
            var offset = 50 - scrolledUp > 0 ? 50 - scrolledUp : 0; 
            $(element[0]).offset({top: offset});

        })
    };
});
```

First of all it detects scroll of `.snap-content` element and not `window` which remains *unscrolled*, if I understand correctly this is reason why it didn't work. Angular-Snap cause to `window` be unscrolled. 
And then I make a simple calculation to find out which `offset` from the top this element should receive and then set this value. Of course in a final version all parameters will be passed in an *Angular way*.

This is working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/HnBM2P5H7D2LPYt7uXve?p=preview

**P.S.** Despite the fact that it's working I feel that it's a little *hackish* solution due to reason that my directive bind to non related element, `.snap-content`. Therefor if somebody will give more beautiful solution I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The author of the Angular-Snap provided solution to this issue here: https://github.com/jtrussell/angular-snap.js/issues/113 You should use:

- angular-snap-only.css - from this repo
- snap.css - from the Snap.js
  repo

Again, please see the detailed explanation here: https://github.com/jtrussell/angular-snap.js/issues/113